# Splitting string data and corresponding data into new row

Tags: stata

I have some data that has a string variable (`US states`), a corresponding integer variable (`enrollment`) and another string.

Unfortunately, some of the cells under the `US states` variable have multiple states listed separated by a semi-colon. I'd like to split these up into different rows and then divide the corresponding enrollment equally among those states.

For example, I have:

```
State       Enrollment   Severity
CA            100          Low
MA;PA         50           Medium
WA;OR;ID      120          High
```

And I want to be able to transform this into:

```
State       Enrollment    Severity
CA             100          Low
MA             25           Medium
PA             25           Medium
WA             40           High
OR             40           High
ID             40           High
```

I have tried separating them using the `split` command and then (in a convoluted fashion, calculating the corresponding enrollment) but I'm not quite sure how to get them on to new rows even with `reshape`.

---

**EDIT:**

I would also like the solution to be able to handle duplicate States.

For example:

```
State       Enrollment   Severity
CA            100          Low
MA;CA         50           Medium
WA;CA;ID      120          High
```

Transformed into:

```
State       Enrollment    Severity
CA             100          Low
MA             25           Medium
CA             25           Medium
WA             40           High
CA             40           High
ID             40           High
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to do what you want using your ***original*** data:

```
clear 
input str10 State Enrollment str10 Severity
"CA" 100 "Low"
"MA;PA" 50 "Medium"
"WA;OR;ID" 120 "High"
end

generate id = _n
split State, p(;)
drop State
reshape long State, i(State?)
drop State?

keep if State != ""
bysort State (id): egen maxval = max(id)
bysort State (id): generate enrol = Enrollment / maxval
drop Enrollment
rename enrol Enrollment

sort id
drop id _j maxval
order State Enrollment Severity

list, abbreviate(20)

     +-------------------------------+
     | State   Enrollment   Severity |
     |-------------------------------|
  1. |    CA          100        Low |
  2. |    MA           25     Medium |
  3. |    PA           25     Medium |
  4. |    OR           40       High |
  5. |    ID           40       High |
  6. |    WA           40       High |
     +-------------------------------+
```

---

**EDIT:**

Here's one way to do what you want using your ***revised*** data:

```
clear
input str10 State Enrollment str10 Severity
"CA"            100          "Low"
"MA;CA"         50           "Medium"
"WA;CA;ID"      120          "High"
end

generate id = _n
split State, p(;)
drop State

reshape long State, i(id)

keep if State != ""
bysort id: egen maxval = count(id)
bysort id: generate enrol = Enrollment / maxval
drop Enrollment
rename enrol Enrollment

sort id
drop id _j maxval
order State Enrollment Severity

list, abbreviate(20)

     +-------------------------------+
     | State   Enrollment   Severity |
     |-------------------------------|
  1. |    CA          100        Low |
  2. |    MA           25     Medium |
  3. |    CA           25     Medium |
  4. |    WA           40       High |
  5. |    CA           40       High |
  6. |    ID           40       High |
     +-------------------------------+
```

Comment: Hi Pearly Spencer, thanks for the response. But this doesn't exactly work. I failed to mention in my original question that the States are repeated as well (i.e. there are multiple instances for CA or any other state) in my datatset. So when I do reshape, I get an error that in the current wide form variable State1 State2... do not uniquely identify the data. Any workarounds that? Thanks!

Comment: Evidently, it works for the example you gave. And we work with what we are given - we are not mind readers. You need to provide an example of how `CA` is repeated. Is it on its own in a different observation or as a group i.e. `CA;MA` etc.? Also, how `enrollment` is to be calculated in this case?

Comment: Hi, you're right - I meant that it does not work for my case and said that I'd fail to mention it earlier and apologize for that. I've made the edits in the question. Sorry about the back and forth. Thanks!